# software virtualization vs hardware virtualization

Tags: hardware, cpu, virtualization, emulation, hypervisor

What actually happens when hardware virtualization is enabled ?
if not, a hypervisor uses binary translation. but, when hardware virtualization is enabled, i have read that it uses trap and emulate.
so the guest code executes directly on the host cpu, if its a privileged instruction the cpu hands over the control to the hypervisor, the hypervisor emulates that instruciton and then executes it.

so, what does the emulation means here ? is the same binary translation carried out when hardware virtualization is enable ?

Answer (score 2):

Enabling HW virtualization sets the `vmx` flag in Intel and `svm` flag in AMD.

In Intel architecture, this allows the user-space calls to run as-is on the lower [protection ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29) as they cannot potentially interfear with the host OS. On the other hand the kernel-space calls of the virualized OS are trapped and binary-translated by the hypervisor.

This is done so as to partly take away the CPU intensive translation for trivial calls. *How-much* of this happens depends on the virtualization type- full, partial or paravirtual.

Binary-translation is a subset of the more elaborate process of emulation. It *alligns* the guest code to be able to run on the host-architecture.

Comment: ya, i have read about the protection rings in various documents, but what specifically is a protection ring ?

Comment: Read this- http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=224
 If you have a specific questions, ask.

Comment: This is a very insightful post- http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/cpu-rings-privilege-and-protection